# Entity Framework How Do I Detach All Objects Of Specific Type From Datacontext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Currently I am trying to implement code prior to my datacontext.savechanges() method that detaches all objects of a specific type from the data context so that they do not get inserted into the database. I know that you can call `dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached` to detach a single entity, but is there a way to detach all objects of a specific type from the context?

Edit: I implemented what Mark C suggested and it compiles, but I get an invalid operation exception when I try to execute the code:

> The entity type DbEntityEntry is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

```
   foreach (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry in this.dataContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Customer>())
            {
                if (dbEntityEntry != null && dbEntityEntry.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified && dbEntityEntry.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged)
                {
                    dataContext.Entry(dbEntityEntry).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
                }
            }
```

Edit #2: After looking at it more closely, I was making a mistake. It appears one needs to specify the entity on DBEntityEntry. With the following change it works:

```
        foreach (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry in this.dataContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Customer>())
        {
            if (dbEntityEntry.Entity != null && dbEntityEntry.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified && dbEntityEntry.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged)
            {
                dataContext.Entry(dbEntityEntry.Entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
        }
```

Thanks to Gert for recommending using EntityState.Unchanged instead of EntityState.Detached.

Comment: Not sure if you should *detach* them. You probably want to mark them as `Unchanged`, because detaching them may also break associations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write something like

```
foreach (DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                if (dbEntityEntry.Entity != null)
                {
                  // Here you can look at typeof and the EntityState
                }
            }
```

Thanks for KeithS for pointing out that you can also use the overload for `ChangeTracker.Entries()` for using specific Entity types.

`this.ChangeTracker.Entries<SomeEntityEntity>()`

Comment: Only suggestion I'd make is to use the generic overload of Entries to make it type-specific. Good answer though.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it compiles, but I get an InvalidOperationException when I run the code:  The entity type DbEntityEntry is not part of the model for the current context.                                      Check my original question for the code I am using.

Comment: It sounds like there are no instances of  `Customer` currenty being tracked by Entity Framework? @Stephen

Comment: Mark - I figured it out. I needed to specify dbEntityEntry.Entity to tell it to detach the actual entity and not the DbEntityEntry itself. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11):

From Efcore 5.0 you can use

```
 _ctx.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

If you don't want all entries see answer from [Mark C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43871169/5031787).

Be aware that this one is slow and can have side effects according Microsoft api documentation in `_ctx.ChangeTracker.Clear()`

Comment: This works like charm!

Comment: This clears ALL entities, not just the ones of a certain type.